# Compact set and uniformly convergence relation with point wise convergence

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Let E and F be two Banach spaces and $ (T_j) \in B(E,F) $. If for all $ x \in E$
$$T(x) = \lim_{j \to \infty} T_j(x) $$
then I proved T is continuous but how can I show $(T_j)$ is uniformly convergence with respect to operator norm T on compact subset of E.

Answer (score 1):

By the Banach-Steinhaus theorem the norms $\|T_n\|$ are uniformly bounded. Denote $M=\sup_n\|T_n\|$. Let $K\subset X$ be compact and $\delta >0.$ There exist finitely many points $x_1,x_2,\ldots, x_k$ such that $$K\subset \bigcup_{j=1}^k\{x\in X\,:\, \|x_k-x\|<\delta\}$$ There exists $N$ such that for $n>N$ we have $$\|T_nx_j-Tx_j\|<\delta,\quad 1\le j\le k$$ For $x\in K$ there is $1\le j\le k$ satisfying $\|x-x_j\|<\delta.$ Then for $n>N$ we get $$\|T_nx-Tx\| \le \|T_nx_j-Tx_j\|\\ +\|T_n(x-x_j)\|+  |T(x-x_j)\|\\ <\delta +2M\|x-x_j\|< (2M+1)\delta $$